# Confused about return variable/value in this recursive reverser of a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I asked a similar question the other day, but didn't really receive the answer I was looking for when it came to the specifics of how this recursive linked list reverse method works.

I have the following method:

```
public Node reverse(Node current)
{
    if(current == null || current.next == null)
    {
        return current;
    }
    Node rest = reverse(current.next);
    current.next.next = current;
    current.next = null;
    return rest;
}
```

If I am modifying the `current` variable after the recursive call, yet returning `rest`, how is `rest` being modified/appended with the next link in the list? When I trace this function, it seems as though `rest` is being broken down to it's last element and then only returning the last element all the way back up.

I don't see how modifying the `current`variable after the recursive call has any effect on the return value at all.

I've traced this function many times and here is an example:

Lets say `Node in = 1` and  `in.next = 2`

The trace seems to go as follows:

`reverse(in) (in is currently 1 , 2)`

`in` is now referred to as `current` from this point forward:

`rest = reverse(current.next) which is equivalent to:
rest = reverse(2)` which returns 2 via base case

now `rest = 2`

current.next.next = current

which makes `current = 1 , 2 , 1 , 2` ???

`current.next = null` which sets current = 1

function returns `rest which is equal to 2` with no `.next` value that I can see as it hasn't been modified anywhere, yet when I test the output from this `rest is 2 , 1`

So how is it that rest is being swapped correctly?

I feel as though there is some sort of reference between the variables that I am not catching, as there are no declarations for `rest.next`

Would anyone mind clearing this up for me?

It appears to be so simple, but it has been over my head until this point. This function IS working correctly, though. It just seems that my traces are inefficient in telling me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because the variables are references to your objects, not the current ones.

Take this example (this is not intended to obey any program language syntax):

```
objects = {e1, e2, e3};
e1.next = e2; e2.next = e3; e3.next = null;
```

At this point, `e1.next` and `e2.next` are recefences to the proper object that exists on memory and `e3.next` is `null`, no object is referenced in this case.

Instead of `x` is a reference to `y`, I will say `x` points `y`, to make the explanation more compact and simple. Anyway, the variables are pointers to the opjects. I also used 2 spaces to indent so the lines won't be so long.

Then you call `reverse(e1)`, let's open the recursion, each line is explained:

```
reverse(e1); // current points e1
{
  if(current == null || current.next == null) // false
  {
    return current; // not executed
  }
  Node rest = reverse(current.next); // recursion, here current points e2
  {
    if(current == null || current.next == null) // false
    {
      return current; // not executed
    }
    Node rest = reverse(current.next); // recursion, here current points e3
    {
      if(current == null || current.next == null) // true
      {
          return current; // returns current that points e3
      }
      current.next.next = current; // not executed
      current.next = null; // not executed
      return rest; // not executed
    } // end of recursion
    // now rest points e3 (the "if" above was true, returning current)
    // current is e2 again
    current.next.next = current; // e2.next.next (this is e3.next) = e2
    current.next = null; // e2.next points nothing
    return rest; // return e3 (rest points e3)
  } // end of recursion
  // now rest points e3
  // current points e1 again
  current.next.next = current; // e1.next.next (this is e2.next) = e1
  current.next = null; // e1.next points nothing
  return rest; // return a pointer to e3
}
```

So, you get `e3`, and `e3.next = e2` and `e2.next = e1` and `e1.next = null`.

Note that the number of recursions is the number of objects on the list minus 1, so if a list have 1000 elements, the stack will be filled with 1000 calls (one normal program call and 999 sucessive recursions). For small devices with small memory this is may be a big problem (may be 20 elements is a problem), but I never had the need to bother about stack size on the PC.

Comment: So you are suggesting that an iterative solution is better for lesser hardware?

Comment: That is the point, the reference is set to null, but the object is still there. If there is other reference (or several) to the object, they will not change. As a side note, the Java programming language eliminates an object when no variable is a reference to it, if I remember correctly, C# do the same. On Pascal and C the objects must be destroied, setting the reference to null is not enough to free the memory used to store the objects. (This is a answer to a deleted comment)

Comment: So just to be clear, the reason that we set `current.next = null` (aside from preventing the last element after reversing from having a next value since the other next values get overwritten) is to destroy the reference to the extra object(s)? I was just testing and ran the method without `current.next = null` and got the same output as if nothing had changed, so I'm assuming there are inherent reasons why we would want current.next to be explicitly null.

Comment: The note about the stack size is for really small memory hardware, it depends on the size of the memory and the amount of objects. For example, I have worked with a device that has 1kb ram, and had to use buffers, at the end a simple division operation was doing a stack overflow (no reference to the site title ;-) ) , I had to rework the code to make the division to work. It all depends on the hardware.

Comment: The `current.next = null` is because each element have a reference to the next, and you want that it is not the next anymore. and the former first element should have no next as it must be the last on the list. On the list this is the only reason. Each object may have as many references as you want, but it will be only one object on the memory, you can destroy some references and mantain the others. Setting a reference to null is usefull for example to not accidentally use a object that has been destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You return whatever the recursive call has returned, *unchanged*. And what has the recursive call returned? The last node in the linked list.

Quite naturally, the last node becomes first in the reversed list.

The last few lines after saving the return value aside deal with linking your current node into the reversed list's *currently last* node, which is your *next*, at that moment.

After the re-linking is done, you're free to return the head of the now fully reversed list:

```
curr ->   next  ->  ....    -> last 
curr ->   next  ->  ... <- ... last
curr ->   <- next   ... <- ... last
. <- curr <- next   ... <- ... last
```

Each invocation of a recursive function maintains it own set of the function's inner variables, on a separate *stack frame*. Example:

```
reverse( {101= val:1 next:102}, {102= val:2 next:103}, {103= val:3 next:null} )

                    => reverse( {102= val:2 next:103}, {103= val:3 next:null} )

                                          =>  reverse( {103= val:3 next:null} )
                                          |            curr                    curr.next == null
                                         <= {103}
                    |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   curr == 102
                    |           curr                   curr.next               curr.next == 103
                    |                                  {103= val:3 next:102}   curr.next.next = curr
                    |           {102= val:2 next:null}                         curr.next = null
                   <= {103}
   |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  curr == 101
   |     curr                    curr.next                                     curr.next == 102
   |                             {102= val:2 next:101}                         curr.next.next = curr
   |     {101= val:1 next:null}                                                curr.next = null
  <= {103}
```

The `current.next = null` line of code is only needed in the very last invocation, which is working with the first node of the original list. It could be skipped in all the other invocations, but this would need more code to arrange for, and would leave the interim lists in an incoherent state.

Comment: but if the only value being passed to the previous call is `2`, then how does it re-link `rest` with the remaining nodes? `current` is only valid in the scope of that one recursive call is it not?

Comment: you return *node*, not the value stored in it. your `curr` node has its data, and its `next` link. after the recursive call with `curr.next`, you have 1. returned value, which is the last node, and 2. your `curr` still points to this `next` node, even if *it* (the `next` node) points now to something else. (what does it point to?) Next, you make this `next` node point to your `current`, and make `current` point to `null`. then you return the set aside value.

Comment: i.e. you change `next` field in the "next" (i.e. `curr.next`) node; you don't change the `result` node (what you call `rest`, but better rename it to `result`) itself. After having manipulated the links, the `curr` becomes linked into the chain which starts at `result` - becomes its *last*.

Answer (score 2):

To take your sample case, Lets say our list has 2 items, **1** & **2** where *1* is at the head, they have these values at the start:

> ***1***
>   Value = 1
>   Next = 2
>
> ***2***
>   Value = 2
>   Next = null

You the call `reverse(1)` and in that context (Lets tag it by depth of recursion, and nest):

> ***R1***
>   Current = 1
>     ***R2***
>     Current = 2
>     (return 2)
>   Rest = 2
>   Current <sub>(1)</sub> .next <sub>(2)</sub>.next <sub>(null before assignment)</sub> = Current <sub>(1)</sub>    | So now 2.next == 1
>   Current <sub>(1)</sub> .next <sub>(2)</sub> = null                                                          | So now 1.next == null
>   (return Rest <sub>(which is 2)</sub>)

Now, had there been another item before 1, when that item would have been processed, it would have set *1*'s *next* to itself, just like in the example above, *1* sets *2*'s *next* to itself.

Comment: I really like how you've laid this out, but I am still not grasping how `rest(2)` becomes attached `current(1)`. I see that `2.next == 1`, but at what point is `rest` defined that it's own node `.next` value is equal to 1?

Comment: In R1, `rest` ***is*** `2`, they are the exact same instance, passed around by reference. Changing `rest` in R1 is *directly* changing `2`.

Comment: Ok, so I think I got this, when we are returning `rest` we are returning the new head, so the old head was set to null and now `rest` is the old `current.next` and `current.next.next` is the old head which is now the tail. And since `rest` is the reference the `current.next`, changing `current.next.next` still affects `rest`

Comment: Yes, I guess that's also a way to put it :-). You might want to play a little with a debugger to see it live. Set a list 1 -> 2 -> 3. step-debug, and watch the 3 list items (value & next for each) after each line of code.

Comment: @Habitat - I wonder why you decided to switch your accepted answer, and more, if you find an answer helpful (not just mine), why don't you upvote? people are trying to help you - at least be kind when they succeed.

Comment: Apologies, his answer really better helped me understand the relationship between rest and current when he mapped it out. Your answer was great, but his answer was exactly what I was looking for. `rest.next == current.next.next` AND the why: they are referencing the same object therefore changing current.next.next is also changing rest.next.

Comment: @Amit you are my hero, for speaking out.